# HTML & CSS progress bar does not stop at the end

Tags: html, css, animation

I have created this progress bar and I just can't make it stop at the end. Currently its stopping at 70% and gets cleared. Any ideas? Is there any kind of animation setting to stop it at 100%?

```css
.wrap {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  height: 10px;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.bar {
  background: #ffcc00;
  height: 10px;
  width: 0%;
}

.animating {
  -webkit-animation: progress 3s ;
}

@-webkit-keyframes progress {
  0% {
    width: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 70%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="bar animating"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try `-webkit-animation: progress 3s forwards;` to keep the state, see [`animation-fill-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode) for details

Comment: Lars, it was just a silly mistake we all make every now and then. The third line from below in his CSS should give you a hint.

Comment: `100% {
    width: 70%;
  }`  change this to `100% {
    width: 100%;
  }`

Comment: Could please clarify your question as there's a little confusion (see answers and comments)? Do you want the progressbar to spread full width (100%) or do you want the animation to stop once it finished? /cc @JPA

Comment: I can't anymore. People have voted me down too much on my correct answer, now I don't have the rights anymore, haha.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`animation-fill-mode: forwards;` or `-webkit-animation: progress 3s forwards;`

Comment: He was asking a different thing James. He just made a silly mistake on the third line from below in his CSS. 70% is not 100%, that's why the bar does not go completely to the right.

Comment: @JPA *I just can't make it **stop** at the end*, Read question carefully.

Comment: HAHAHA, exactly: He wants the bar to stop at the end and not at 70%.

Comment: Even if OP wants to stop it at the end (100%), still this answer is correct.

Comment: It is a matter of how you interpret his question I guess. But if you look at his example you understand what he means. So, please look at his example.

Comment: So to conclude: no problem man, but read the question in full next time OK?

Comment: @AbhishekPandey - you're right. I was wrong. Guess I was put on the wrong foot by the immediately following question of "Is there any kind of animation setting to stop it at 100%?" Pfeew.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use 100% in:

```
@-webkit-keyframes progress {
  0% {
    width: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 70%; /* edit to 100% */
  }
}
```

Comment: What, this is strange? I give the correct answer and I get -1.

Comment: I think the question was rather unclear; I understood it as the animation was looping indefinitely whereas @JPA understood it as your progress bar was not reaching 100% width. JPA has a right answer; but for the wrong question :D

Comment: No Lars, please execute his example and you see what he means. I understand the question is ambiguous but there is only ONE solution for him. And that is to change 70% to 100% in the third line from below in his CSS.
James, dito.

Comment: Have you even tried his example or your solution in that example?

Comment: I think the op's problem was that he/she *wanted* the bar to stop at 70%, but if you run the code snippet, the bar reaches 70% and then disappears. I think he/she wanted the bar to remain at 70% after the animation had *ended*, rather than wanting the bar to reach the *end*. Either way, I upped your answer as I do think the question is equivocal.

Answer (score 0):

A Fancy version

```css
  .wrap {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  height: 10px;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.wrap div {
  background-color: #ffcc00;
  height: 10px;
  width: 0%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  animation: loadbar 3s;
  -webkit-animation: loadbar 3s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes loadbar {
  0% {
    width: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
  }
  @keyframes loadbar {
    0% {
      width: 0%;
    }
    100% {
      width: 100%;
    }
  }
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="bar animating"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This does not work. Please execute the example (brilliant system by the way stacky ;-) and you see that the bar stops at 70%.

Comment: made it 100% was wondering if he wanted to stop at 70% as it was vanishing, edited to 100

Comment: Brilliant, changing your answer to make it look like my answer and therefore correct at last.

Comment: All your additions were not neccesary. It was just a silly mistake by the TS, mistakes we all make every now and then.